# FLASK - How can I show a loading screen while my function run in background, and then return the html page from my function?

Tags: python, html, flask

I have some functions on my flask script, and this take so much time to execute. At this time I want to show something like a loading page while the script runs.

I tried so many manners to do it but no success

```
@app.route('/script')
def foo():
  global cookie
  if cookie == 1:
    try:
        path = "script.py"
        os.system(path) #while this run, I want to show the loading page, and then return the output*       
        return render_template('output.html') #output*
    except Exception:
        return  render_template('error.html')
return render_template('login_error.html')
```

Comment: This could also be done with JavaScript on the initial page. You could make an AJAX request “behind the scenes” to the Flask script and then display the response.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris commented, you need to use JavaScript to display a loading page.

Below is a simple code snippet that may help you get started.

**HTML**: Let's assume that you have an anchor that triggers /script call.

```
<a id="scriptCall">Run a script</a>
<div id="loadingImage" style="display:none;">
 <!-- your image tag goes here -->
</div>
```

**JS**: Contains an Ajax call to server (to hit /script). Need JQuery.

```
$("#scriptCall").click( function()
    {
        // when a button is clicked, you make an Ajax call.
        $('#loadingImage').show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/script',
            success: function (resp) {
                $('#loadingImage').hide();
             }
        });
    });
```